# How to get list of folders via POP3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pop3

I'm using POP3 to fetch emails from gmail, I want to fetch a list of folders present in my gmail account but not finding a way of doing it. In IMAP there's a method `list("","*")` through which we can fetch the folders and then by using `select("folder_name")` we could fetch the emails.

How to fetch the list of folders via POP3. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use imap?

Comment: It's a requirement, user can choose any one of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POP3 does not have the concept of folders. It is a very old mail protocol. There is only the Inbox. If you ever see folders on a POP3 client (like in outlook), that is a client side implementation. There are no folders on a POP3 server.

If you need access to the Gmail folders, you need to use IMAP.

hth,
Dave